# Updating AndroidView state in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Came across a curious situation with AndroidView this morning.

I have a ProductCard interface that looks like this

```
interface ProductCard {
    val view: View
    fun setup(
        productState: ProductState,
        interactionListener: ProductCardView.InteractionListener
    )
}
```

This interface can be implemented by a number of views.

A composable that renders a list of `AndroidView` uses `ProductCard` to get a view and pass in state updates when recomposition happens.

```
@Composable
fun BasketItemsList(
    modifier: Modifier,
    basketItems: List<ProductState>,
    provider: ProductCard,
    interactionListener: ProductCardView.InteractionListener
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        items(basketItems) { product ->
            AndroidView(factory = { provider.view }) {
                Timber.tag("BasketItemsList").v(product.toString())
                provider.setup(product, interactionListener)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this sample, any interaction with the ProductCard view’s (calling `ProductCard.setup()`) doesn’t update the screen. Logging shows that the state gets updated but the catch is that it’s only updated once per button. For example, I have a favourites  button. Clicking it once pushes a state update only once, any subsequent clicks doesn’t propagate. Also the view itself doesn’t update. It’s as if it was never clicked.

Now changing the block of `AndroidView.update` to use `it` and casting it as a concrete view type works as expected. All clicks propagate correctly and the card view gets updated to reflect the state.

```
@Composable
fun BasketItemsList(
    modifier: Modifier,
    basketItems: List<ProductState>,
    provider: ProductCard,
    interactionListener: ProductCardView.InteractionListener
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        items(basketItems) { product ->
            AndroidView(factory = { provider.view }) {
                Timber.tag("BasketItemsList").v(product.toString())
//                provider.setup(product, interactionListener)
                (it as ProductCardView).setup(product, interactionListener)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? why does using `ProductCard` not work while casting the view to its type works as expected?

---

**Update 1**

Seems like casting to `ProductCard` also works

```
    @Composable
    fun BasketItemsList(
        modifier: Modifier,
        basketItems: List<ProductState>,
        provider: ProductCard,
        interactionListener: ProductCardView.InteractionListener
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
            items(basketItems) { product ->
                AndroidView(factory = { provider.view }) {
                    Timber.tag("BasketItemsList").v(product.toString())
    //                provider.setup(product, interactionListener)
                    (it as ProductCard).setup(product, interactionListener)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So the question is why do we have to use `it` inside `AndroidView.update` instead of any other references to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is I was missing the `key` value which is needed for `LazyColumn` items in order for compose to know which item has changed and call update on it.